# intellij shortcut for cursor step back?

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse I can go to the last position of the cursor with `Alt + left arrow`. With `Alt + Right` Arrow I can go forward with the cursor. Which shortcut do this in Intellij?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ it should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> for Windows/Linux.

On OS X it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>.

These keyboard shortcuts correspond to *Back* and *Forward* actions. You can change them in Settings/Keymap if the default ones don't work (I think that these shortcuts are already used by the system in Ubuntu for instance).

Sources and other useful shortcuts:

- [Keyboard shortcut reference for Windows/Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)
- [Keyboard shortcut reference for OS X](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf)

Comment: Linux might need `Super` key (aka `Win` key).
So  combination is `CTRL`+`Super`>+`ALT`+`Left/Right` arrow

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:
<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + left/right arrow
On Win:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + left/right arrow

Additionally, quick key <kbd>command</kbd> + E can show you recent files, this also helps conveniently.